# Simulating an XSS attack does not work

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, xss

Please refer below my code to simulate an XSS attack. But unfortunately it is not working. 
Now when I enter `<script type="text/javascript">alert("Hacked")</script>`, shouldnt a message box be thrown. But it is not shown. Though i can see it in unencoded form in the view source. It should be some small error but I am not able to figure it out.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Nothing entered";
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult Index(string Id)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = Id;
            return View();
        }

    }
```

And the view code is

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="Id" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
<h2>The Data you entered is</h2>
<h1>@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Message)</h1>
```

Comment: You seem to be using some web development framework. Can you please disclose which one?

Comment: `alert('hacked')` is just text. Do you mean `<script>alert('hacked')</script>`?

Comment: Ha actually i did type the script tag but i guess the SO website blocked it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now when I enter alert("Hacked"), shouldnt a message box be thrown.

No, of course not. `alert("Hacked")` is a javascript function whereas you have Html.Raw inside an `<h1>` tag.

So you end up with the following markup:

```
<h1>alert("Hacked")<h1>
```

from which you cannot expect any message boxes to be thrown. If you want to throw something make sure you are hacking it right, i.e. by typing the following in your textbox:

```
<script>alert("Gotcha this time")</script>
```

Comment: That does not work too. The html view source is <h1><script>alert("Gotcha this time")</script></h1>

Comment: @ckv Define "does not work". Do you not get an alert? Do you get an error in your console?

Comment: This should work. If inside your markup you have `<h1><script>alert("Gotcha this time")</script></h1>`, then you should get a javascript message. Unless of course you have disabled javascript execution in your browser :-) Or maybe you have some other javascript error in your page which has prevented any js to execute. Look at the js console in your browser.

Comment: @ckv How are you viewing the source?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: The chrome browser was throwing the following error Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request. Tested with IE and it worked. Thanks